# Any reason for this call to Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: .net, reflection, activator, createinstance

I'm maintaining someone else's code and they have this section in a method:

```
object ReportCriteriaInstance =
        Activator.CreateInstance(
                typeof(MyCompany.Utils.ReportStructure.ReportSearchCriteria));

//ReportCriteria is passed in as a method parameter
ReportCriteriaInstance = ReportCriteria;
```

I don't know why they're setting `ReportCriteriaInstace` to a different value one line after instantiating it with `CreateInstance()`.

Aside from that, 
because we're passing in a known type to `CreateInstance` (`MyCompany.Utils.ReportStructure.ReportSearchCriteria`) is there any reason not to use new() instead?  Some default, parameterless constructor reason I'm not getting maybe?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is if the assembly is loaded dynamically and thus you don't have the name at compile time.

Comment: Put a // before that line and move on with your life.  Some day you might figure out why.

Comment: @Hans Passant: That's not save until proven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an abandoned effort to implement poor man's DI container. Later on the object was just passed in, so the code can be safely removed (unless there is a default `ReportSearchCriteria` constructor that has some potential side effects).

Comment: Looks like there is(was) a side effect in a ReportSearchCriteria class

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert code to the following, avoiding side effects of the refactorings entirely:

```
var ReportSearchCriteriaInstance = new MyCompany.Utils.ReportStructure.ReportSearchCriteria();
object ReportCriteriaInstance = ReportCriteria;
```